# Excel VBA - How to add new row at the end of a sheet only if the new row differs from the last row?

Tags: excel, vba, row

I am trying to avoid duplicite rows so I want to check if the data on the last row are different from the new values and if so then add new line with the new data.

Somehow this is not working and new values keep being added:

```
Set ws = Worksheets("mySheet")
lastrow = ws.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

If item = ws.Cells(lastrow , 5).Value And color = ws.Cells(lastrow, 8).Value And price = ws.Cells(lastrow, 9).Value Then
 '   do nothing
 Else
'  add new rows
   newrow = ws.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws.Cells(newrow , 5).Value = item
    ws.Cells(newrow , 8).Value = color
    ws.Cells(newrow , 9).Value = price
End If
```

Obviously I have other columns filled with other data but these are not crucial for the duplicity. My first column contains DateTime values.

Comment: you'd better ass some examples of your data causing the unwanted behavior. and please clarify: is your "first column" column 5?

Comment: No, first column is column 1

Comment: You were right. The problem was with the values in the condition..

Comment: fine. you may want to adopt my code to both shorten it down and take aboard a good practice in range referencing

Answer (score 0):

without any data example is hard to tell what's going on

in the meanwhile you may want to try this little refactoring

```
With Worksheets("mySheet") '<--| reference your relevant worksheet
    With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) '<--| reference its column "A" last not empty cell
        If Not (item = .Offset(, 4).Value And Color = .Offset(, 7).Value And Price = .Offset(, 8).Value) Then '<-- check if write a new record: do it referencing cells to be compared as offset from referenced one
            .Offset(1, 4).Value = item ' <--| reference new record cells as offsetted 1 row doen the referenced one
            .Offset(1, 7).Value = Color ' <--| same as above
            .Offset(1, 8).Value = Price ' <--| same as above
        End If
    End With
End With
```